# How do I run 'vbeinfo'?

Tags: grub2, uefi, display-resolution

The instructions in `/etc/default/grub` say to run `vbeinfo`,

> ```
> # The resolution used on graphical terminal
> # note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
> # you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
> #GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480
> ```

but that command isn't found in GRUB,

```
grub> vbeinfo
error: can't find command `vbeinfo'.
```

or in the terminal:

```
$ vbeinfo
vbeinfo: command not found
```

Where is it?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

If anyone still cares its actually

```
videoinfo
```

for grub-efi

Comment: Oh yes I do care! Native resolution reduces screen refresh rate to what looks like 1 fps on a laptop I have here. The problem didn't get resolved in past releases and it would drive the person who is going to receive this laptop soon crazy. 1024x768 runs fine on T560 so thank you very much! :)

Comment: /usr/sbin/hwinfo --framebuffer

Answer (score 6):

vbeinfo is a module in grub-pc, not in grub-efi.  I suppose you could boot an external media with the old grub and run vbeinfo, but it is not a part of the new grub.  Probably secure boot led to some restrictions on what grub can run.