# Can You Change or Control the Dual Boot Screen

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

I made my Win XP system a dual boot with Ubuntu Desktop 20.04. The little screen (I don't know what you call it) that comes up giving you the options of booting into Ubuntu or Windows appears in the top left corner of my monitor and the font is too small to read easily, and it disappears too quickly. Is there a way to make the font bigger and give me more time to select an option? Actually I have about 5 options:))

Thanks
Zeek

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a way. It is called "gfx mode" where you could change the resolution of your graphical terminal. That "little screen" you were talking about is the Grub bootloader - and that runs in a terminal.

Since Grub runs in a very early stage, the value to insert depends on your hardware (namely the GPU). So I'd do the following steps:

- Use a terminal to enter `nano /etc/default/grub`
- Change the following line to `GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480`
- Save the change and execute `sudo update-grub`

Reboot and you'll get a very coarse screen with a big font. Now you could check (and read) which resolutions you could enter instead by checking the `vbeinfo`. But this is explained [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/577486/how-do-i-run-vbeinfo).
If you've got an NVIDIA graphics card, things could be different, but you didn't mention it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use grub customizer which is a very easy to use interface if you are not comfortable with the terminal.

You can make changes, including making the resolution smaller (so it looks bigger) and also change what appears in the list.

Make sure to read this all before you try it; like anything else, you don't want to mess up grub or you might not load any operating system at all.

https://tipsonubuntu.com/2016/10/15/install-grub-customizer-ubuntu-16-10/